# Init an empty NSZone struct with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In Swift 2, I was able to initialize an empty `NSZone` struct like so:

```
let z = NSZone() // ObjectiveC.NSZone
```

I used this to stub test calls that required `NSZone`.  With Swift 3, the interface was changed so that the initializer is no longer available:

Swift 2.3:

```
public struct NSZone : NilLiteralConvertible {
    public init()
    /// Create an instance initialized with `nil`.
    public init(nilLiteral: ())
}
```

Swift 3:

```
public struct NSZone {
}
```

Is Apple pushing to use an optional `NSZone` instead of the old `NSZone()` initializer which initialized `NSZone` with a `nil` value?

Try to extend `NSZone` to add an initializer results in an error:

```
extension NSZone {
    init() { } // Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Swift open source project's [design doc](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md) for importing ObjC API into Swift 3:

> **Nullable NSZone parameters** are given a default value of `nil`. Zones are essentially unused in Swift and should always be `nil`.

If you're testing any calls that require a zone, you should be passing `nil` anyway.